How to run VS Code extension with arguments
Specifically, I'm trying to run the Reverse Search extension with a predefined set of files to include and exclude.  Currently, when I run the extension, I need to input a search term, include files, and exclude files.  I want to use a file to define my file includes and excludes.
As far as I can tell, the extension itself provides no way configuring the search to always include/exclude certain files.
My thought was to build a task like this:
    {
        "label": "reverse-search",
        "command": "${command:reverseSearch.run}",
        "args": [
            "${input:searchTerm}",
            "**/FolderToInclude/**/*",
            "**/File1ToExclude **/File2ToExclude"
        ],                
        "problemMatcher": []            
    }

But, when I run this task, the args are ignored.
I don't have any experience writing VS Code extensions, but I think modifying the source code for the extension would be more work than I can afford to invest in this. Is there something I can do to avoid typing args 2 and 3 every time?
